# Co-spanning tree

Tags: language-agnostic, graph, graph-algorithm, spanning-tree

Does anyone know that what is co spanning tree. If there are some good answers then it would be really good to have an example also.

Answer (score 1):

From [The Structurally Optimal Dual Graph Pyramid and Its Application in Image Partitioning](http://books.google.ee/books?id=h0Cpnmk_pkAC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=%22cospanning%20tree%22&source=bl&ots=muBDzII91i&sig=VPG_9kamg4wL7A4erxB2blQjXyc&hl=en&ei=jhKLTpD3OYjf4QSF6LXNAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22cospanning%20tree%22&f=false)

[image]

In other words, it is basic graph theory - You can't expect to understand what it is about without at least trying to study it firsthand.